# Ember.js: how can I find all bindings for a component without knowing the model and properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, data-binding, web-component

How can I find all bindings for a given component at runtime. Like in example below, I would like to get the attribute name ('value') and the bound model property ('model.firstName') either from the route or controller.

Example:
Html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
<x-input label="Name" value={{model.firstName}}></x-input>
</script>
```

JS

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
    return (this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName')).trim();
  })
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  person: null,
  model: function () {
    if(!this.person) {
      this.person = App.Person.create({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
      })
    }
    return this.person;
  },
  actions: {}
});
```

I am trying to use webcomponents and not ember components ({{...}}). One way data-binding works for the above example, but I am trying to figure out if I can wire two way databinding to this. I am very new to ember and wanted some pointers if there is an API to get all existing bindings for a component.

Comment: This are ember internals. You probably can heck something around with private APIs, but why the heck do you want to build your own view layer? Also what ember version are you using? Notice also that the ember internals about the rendering will change in near future with glimmer. Check [tildeio/glimmer](https://github.com/tildeio/glimmer) for the code. I *stongly* recommend you to go with `ember-cli` until you are much more experienced with ember and try not to fight the framework. Maybe also check out the slack channel if you want to discuss your problems.

Comment: Thanks @Lux for the pointers. I am trying to use Polymer's events to auto-wire some of the otherwise boiler-plate code (Ex: calling a setter on "model.firstName") to get 2-way databinding to work with Ember. Our team is still on Ember 1.13.x, but an upgrade is under discussion.

Comment: Really, don't fight the framework! Use ember components and follow the conventions. And try to jump to `2.x` and `ember-cli` asap. I've done that upgrade recently and believe me, its worth it!